# Display name using condition in TbGridView

Tags: yii

I have stored the status value 0 or 1 which means it Enabled or Disabled. I am displaying values in the TbGridView. In status field the display value is 0 or 1. But i want to display Enabled or Disabled.

My code is here,

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'id'=>'states-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'state_val',
    'state_name',
    'status',
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
         'template'=>'{update}',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
[
'attribute' => 'status',
'value' => '($data->status) ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"',  
],
```